# using async/await with redux thunk

Tags: async-await, react-redux

i'm new to redux/react and trying to put together a login page.  But for some reason the code within the async parameters are not running.  I was trying to write it so that I don't need to put in a bunch of .then statements.  My code is below.

```
export function signIn (email, password) {
console.log('trying to login');
return async function (dispatch) {
  const error = validateCredentials(email, password);
    if (error) {
        return error;
    }

    try {
        console.log('gather credentials');
        const geoipjson = await geoip();
        console.log(geoipjson);
        const ip = geoipjson.ip;
        console.log(ip);
        const country = geoipjson.country_name;
        console.log(country);
        const fp = await getFingerprint();
        console.log(fp);

        const res = await authenticateUser(email, password, ip, country, fp);
        if (!res.jwt) {
            return res;
        }

        const update_error = await updateLoginStamp(res.jwt);
        if (update_error) {
            return update_error;
        }

        setCookie("jwt", res.jwt);

        console.log('user authenticated');
        dispatch({type: USER_AUTHENTICATED});
        history.push('/');
        return null;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('authentication error');
        dispatch({type: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error});
        return error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it logging an error at the beginning? Also, can you post the validateCredentials code?

```
  const error = validateCredentials(email, password);
  if (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
     return error;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured out the solution with some help from a blog entry. I realized the code after,

```
return async function (dispatch) { ... }
```

wasn't being called.  I was calling this function from the main app.js, but needed to "dispatch" from the component making the call, to make use of the middleware thunk.  I didn't understand the whole answer but it has to do with binding to an actioncreator.  The blog here handled it pretty nicely, the best solution I could find.

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {action1, action2} from "myActions";


const MyComponent = (props) => (
    <div>
        <button onClick={props.action1}>Do first action</button>
        <button onClick={props.action2}>Do second action</button>
    </div>
)

// Passing an object full of actions will automatically run each action 
// through the bindActionCreators utility, and turn them into props

export default connect(null, {action1, action2})(MyComponent);
```

the full explanation and the blog entry can be found [here](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/).  This solved a huge problem for me and was done in an excellent way, in my opinion.